# Proof that the graph is the sum of three edge-disjoint bipartite graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Question from an old exam:

> Let $ G $ be a graph with a chromatic number $ \chi(G) \leq 8 $. Prove that $ G $ is the sum of three edge-disjoint bipartite graphs.

I tried interpreting each of eight colors as a tuple $ (a_1, a_2, a_3) $ where $ a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \{1,2\} $.

Next, pairs of connected vertices whose tuples differ at exactly one position will be in the first bipartite graph. Similarly, vertices whose tuples differ at exactly two positions are in the second bipartite graph, and if the tuples differ at three positions, the connected vertices go into the third bipartite graph.

However, this approach has a problem as it creates odd-length cycles. For example, $(2,1,1), (1,2,1), (1,1,2)$ are connected to each other. And in a bipartite graph, there can't be cycles of odd length.

What could be another way to approach this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You only need to show that the complete graph $K_8$ has this property, that is something you can do by trial and error "by hand".

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I can definitely do that, but why is it enough to check only $K_8$? Then for sure all subgraphs of $K_8$ meet the conditions of the question, but what about other graphs?

Comment: That part you already know from your first attempt - if you know how to partition edges between labels/colors, then you will partition edges between vertices the same way.